# Extracting attribute-value from fuzzy text

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, spelling

I'm using an OCR library to extract products specifications from images. I'm first focusing on notebooks.For example:

```
Processor 
Processor model: Intel N3540 
Clock speed: 2.16 GHz 
Memory 
Internal: 4 GB 
Hard disk 
Capacity: 1 TB
```

or:

```
TOSHIBA 
SATELLITE C50-5302 
PENTIUM 
TOSHIBA  
DISPLAY 15.6 
4GB 
DDR3 
500
```

The OCR is not perfect and sometimes what would be C10 ends up being CIO and other similar things.

I'd like to extract the attribute-value pairs but I don't know how to approach this problem.

I'm thinking about building a file with all the notebooks and microprocessors I can get(because brand, memory and hard drive capacity are pretty limited) and then use a NLP library to extract the entities from text. The problem also is that sometimes there are spelling errors so it's not as easy as comparing the exact values.

How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As for spelling errors, I'd suggest to, if possible, obtain an ambiguous and probabilistic output of the OCR system. Considering your CIO example, I is much graphically closer to 1 than to other characters. If no such an output is available, you may consider using some sort of weighted edit distance between characters.

For named entity recognition, work has been done for recognizing named entities from noisy input, mostly for ASR sources (as much as I know). See how word confusion networks does handle this, for instance [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0885230805000495).

As a final step, you'll probably need a joint task for OCR correction and named entity recognition. This will probably require to define what entities are likely for your domain: what tokens are expected to describe CPU speed, storage capacity, computer brands, etc. You may either manually implement rules or mine data from existing databases. As a final step, you'll probably have to somehow adjust the rate of expected OCR error correction to extract correct attribute-value pairs without adding false positive.

Don't hesitate to keep us informed about the solution you experiment!